# getting Datakeynames value for each row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to get the all the data from one table and stored that in dataset and have to insert those values in another table. I have selected values using datakeynames of gridview there are more records in CartGridview but it takes only one record that is latest value How to get the all records from gridview using datakeynames?? It inserts only latest value.

```
protected void Gridcart_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in Gridcart.Rows)
        {
            string ID = Gridcart.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
            Application["Id"] = ID;
        }

    }


protected void orderimgbtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Convert.ToDecimal(Label1.Text) > 0)
        {

            string proid = Application["Id"].ToString();
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select tpd.productid,tpd.productname,tpd.ProductImage,tpd.price,tpd.qty,tpd.totalcost,tpd.cdate from rsa_addtocart tpd where tpd.productid=" + proid + "", con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "tbl_tp");
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables["tbl_tp"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                using (var command = new SqlCommand("insert into rsa_Orderconfirmation(UserId, productid, productname, ProductImage, price, qty, totalcost, cdate) values (@UserId, @productid, @productname, @ProductImage, @price, @qty, @totalcost, @cdate)", con))
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < this.Gridcart.Rows.Count; z++)
                    {


                        command.Parameters.Clear();
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Session["users"]);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productid", ds.Tables[0].Rows[z][0]);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", ds.Tables[0].Rows[z][1]);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductImage", ds.Tables[0].Rows[z][2]);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", ds.Tables[0].Rows[z][3]);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", ds.Tables[0].Rows[z][4]);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalcost", ds.Tables[0].Rows[z][5]);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cdate", DateTime.Now);

                        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            try
                            {
                                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                con.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }

                    Response.Redirect("~/BillingDetails.aspx");
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

While Inserting values in rsa_Orderconfirmation getting error like There is no row at position 1. Please guide me to solve this.